# Extension to the Airplane Probability Problem

Tags: probability

Can someone explain the answer to this question:

'Imagine there are a 100 people in line to board a plane that seats 100. The first person in line realizes he lost his boarding pass so when he boards he decides to take a random seat instead. Every person that boards the plane after him will either take their "proper" seat, or if that seat is taken, a random seat instead.  Question: What is the probability that the last person that boards will end up in his/her proper seat.'

If instead of only the first person having lost their ticket the first two people have lost their tickets and take random seats?

Comment: What have you tried?  I suggest studying the classical solutions to the original problem to see if you can adapt the same arguments.  Then, try it with smaller numbers.  If you have $2$ people the answer is clearly $\frac 12$.  What about $3$ people?  $4$?  Maybe you'll see a pattern which you could then try to prove.

Comment: For 2 people it is 1/3 and for 3 1/4 so should be a 1/n+1 relationship but I'm not fully sure how to prove this

Comment: and if only the 1st person has lost their ticket it should be 1/2